# Reduce height between Bootstrap form components

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and its form components:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

How do I reduce the vertical distance between two components and also make them smaller?

Example: In the link above, in the 'Validation states', how do I reduce the gap between 'input with warning' row and 'input with error' row, and how do I reduce the height of the text input?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to move the label closer to the input you need to change the width.

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    width:160px;
}
```

To change the height of the inputs you need to change the "height" property for this selector.

```
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
   height:20px;
}
```

To reduce the height between rows you need to change the margin of the row.

```
.form-horizontal .control-group {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

These are default styles which are used in bootstrap.css. If you want to override these I would suggest setting a top level class on your page. This way you can override the defaults without rewriting the bootstrap.css file...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code helps shrinking the components and labels but it's moving the components and labels to right. Example - the component at row 3 column 3, flots to row 3 column 4.

Answer (score 3):

For the form validation change this rule in the CSS

```
.form-horizontal .control-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

To find these, in Chrome (or Firefox with Firebug) right click the element in that link above.  Choose inspect element from the list. Then in the property inspector that opens (in the elements tab hover over the items until you find the one showing the attribute you want to change. In this case it was a dive with a class of "control-group warning" Click that element and on the right of the inspector it will show you the relevant CSS rules. You can then search your CSS and fix the rules. You can also actually change it in the inspector and see the result live on the page you're inspecting.