# How to reduce height between components on bootstrap 3 MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Can someone please tell me what needs to be implemented in the code bellow to adjust (decrease) the height between the components?

I have tried several combinations, including using margin-bottom:5px in each possible component but at no result.

NOTE: I found this solution (Bootstrap 2) but it didn't worked on my case.
[Reduce height between bootstrap form components](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942310/reduce-height-between-bootstrap-form-components&ei=zha5UsjPOqb82gXt4IHICA&usg=AFQjCNHyoOoOi-89t2QMuMFu3u8BD3oibg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.b2I)

The closest think I found on bootstrap.css (related to the above answer) was the one bellow, which I promptly set to 1px but nothing changed

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1px; 
}
```

// THIS IS THE SAMPLE CODE:

```
@model Models.Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <form role="form">

        <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label input-sm" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "control-label input-sm" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline input-group-sm" role="form">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "control-label input-sm" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "control-label input-sm" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zip, new { @class = "control-label input-sm" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Zip, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the parsed html.

The class

```
input-group-sm
```

Needs to be

```
input-group input-group-sm
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

You also have a div.form-inline in there, just use a row, then use the columns as you have them.

All CSS affecting core bootstrap.css must come after. So add this to an import in the LESS after the bootstrap.less is compiled or if using CSS, put it after all other CSS.

For vertical height between .form-group, adjust the css as needed (put a class on the form to not affect all forms):

```
/*vertical height between form-groups*/
.my-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 4px
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .my-form .row {
        margin-left: -1px;
        margin-right: -1px;
    }
    .my-form [class*="col-"] {
        padding: 0 2px
    }
}
```

**Here's an example of using a row inside a form and adjusting the vertical and horizontal width between columns and form-groups:**

### http://jsbin.com/omEqUFi/1/edit**

Comment: Thanks so much for such a complete answer, the hints and the examples.